# Frustrating error: Throwing KeyError when creating new columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is weird, I have used this code before and it worked. But now it throws me a KeyError saying:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['0', '1'], dtype='object')] are in the
> [columns]"

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[[str(c) for c in range(2)]] = [[5,6],[6,6], [7,7]]
```

I have even asked my friend to test it on his side and he has no issue executing the code without any errors. Also, my `Pandas` version is indeed different, one is 1.1.4, one is 1.0.3.

Also, if anyone has an elegant solution using `.loc` or `.iloc` please let me know as well. I am really frustrated why this does not work on my computer when versioning is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me working well.

Another solution is create new DataFrame and add to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[6,6], [7,7]], index=df.index, columns=['0','1']))
print (df)
   col1  col2  0  1
0     1     3  5  6
1     2     4  6  6
2     3     5  7  7
```